# Running matlab in background with an interface

Tags: java, c++, python, matlab, interface

I have a matlab script and I would like to build an interface using any other programming language, I would like for the user to enter two numbers using the interface and chose the operation that he wants to perform, I want matlab to run and perform this operation on the input that the user input and give the output of the operation on that interface 
I do not want to build the GUI using matlab since I want to use that program in some devices that do not have matlab ( so I'll be using the matlab running engine )
is there anyway I can do that using c++, python or Java ?

Comment: I thought matlab allowed you to make UIs. Why not use that?

Comment: You can execute java 1.6 within matlab. Also matlab has its gui development tools.

Comment: @Borgleader I want to run that program on any pc without having to install matlab (using matlab running engine only to do the operations)

Comment: @Marcin how can I use java to do that ?

Comment: @Lily You can check 'Overview of Java Interface': http://goo.gl/878HB

Answer (score 1):

A MATLAB command can be executed in the background with the following line:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -nodesktop -minimize -r "run [your_script_path]; exit"
```

With this configuration, you can run a script without a display and then console is closed. However, this option has too much opening/closing time overhead and two more feasible options can be:

- using another scripting language which is light weight like Python

or

- implementing the GUI directly in MATLAB.

Comment: how can I use another language ?
any useful links ?
Note: I'm using windows

Comment: @Lili There is an unoffical matlab python interface. Just look for mlabwrap v1.1

Comment: @Marcin I tried using this but I faced a lot of problems installing mlabwarp and getting it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the compiler of Matlab 
I just quote the description of this tool from the website.

> MATLAB Compiler™ lets you share your MATLAB® application as an executable or a shared library. Executables and libraries created with MATLAB Compiler use a runtime engine called the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR). The MCR is provided with MATLAB Compiler for distribution with your application and can be deployed royalty-free.
>   https://www.mathworks.com.au/products/compiler/

Then you can just run the executable from your script.
If you want to use c++, take a look to the Mex function. It's a way to call some matlab lines from your soft.